# Links to a review or to the tab review in OpenCart (2.x)

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm looking for a way to get a direct link to a specific review (using `review_id`), such as :

```
<a href="index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1&review_id=1">Review #1</a>
```

If it's not possible, a link to the tab review could possibly be sufficient, such as:

```
<a href="index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1#tab-review">Reviews</a>
```

I have found some references for the former version of OpenCart (1.5.x), such as [Link to select a tab](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=63601) or [Linking to different product tab using text link](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=56547), but nothing for the current version (2.x). Does anybody have an idea to get links like this?

Comment: Both can be done by coding.

Comment: You could create the link on the product controller page using `$data['review_link'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id'] . '&review_id='.$this->request->get['review_id]);` provided you pass the review id in the url, and access the review link in the template as `$review_link`

Comment: @RahulChandrasekharan: Thank you for this suggestion: I'll try to test this using a vQmod script...